# RewriteRule Redirects paths not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

I moved my website to a new server with a new CMS so I had to make a lot of 301 Redirects. 'Normal' 301 redirects didn't recognize the url path of my old urls so I tried to make RewriteRules, this is what it looks like now:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^Category http://www.example.com/category [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Category/Subcategory http://www.example.com/category-subcategory [R=301,L]
```

The first RewriteRule works, but as soon as there is a second path in the old url (the second example) the redirect will point to the main cateagy and not the subcategory. So it's basically ignoring the url paths...

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert your rules, or to add a $ at the end of the first one :

```
RewriteRule ^Category$ http://www.example.com/category [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Category/Subcategory http://www.example.com/category-subcategory [R=301,L]
```

Explanation : Category/Subcategory is also matching the first rule, and as you have use a L flag in the first one, Apache will just use this first rule and don't bother to look further.

Answer (score 0):

For general purpose solution, quoting from [apache rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html):

> **Move Homedirs to Different Webserver Description:**
>
> Many webmasters have asked for a solution to the following situation:
>
> They wanted to redirect just all homedirs on a webserver to another webserver. They usually need such things when establishing a newer webserver which will replace the old one over time.
>
> Solution:
>
> The solution is trivial with mod_rewrite. On the old webserver we just
>   redirect all /~user/anypath URLs to http://example.com/~user/anypath.
>
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule   ^/~(.+)  http://example.com/~$1  [R,L]

In your case URL structure has changed so ôkio's suggestion would work.